# gcc version mention in kernel module makefile

Tags: gcc, makefile, linux-kernel, kernel-module

How to mention the gcc version in makefile while compiling the kernel module?
I used **make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-** to build the module but it gives an error that arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: command not found. Bit I have arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.3, so how can I mention gcc-4.3 in makefile ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

```
MAKEFLAGS="CC=gcc-4.4"
```